# Django Channels - Custom Authentication Middleware raises: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-channels

I have created a custom token authentication middleware.

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        # Close old database connections to prevent usage of timed out connections
        sync_to_async(close_old_connections)()

        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        try:
            token_name, token_key = headers[b'sec-websocket-protocol'].decode().split(', ')
            
            if token_name == 'Token':
                token = sync_to_async(Token.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(key=token_name)

                scope['user'] = token.user
            
            else:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        return self.inner(scope)
```

When I run it, an exception happens when I run `scope['user'] = token.user`

`[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'user'`

I tried awaiting the Token query like this:

```py
token = await sync_to_async(Token.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(key=token_name)
```

and I added async in front of the `__call__` function, but then the following error is raised before any of the code inside the `__call__` function runs:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

I am using Django v3.0.6 and Django Channels v2.4.0

Comment: Check [these docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html) and [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html). Then see if you're still stuck.

Comment: @Melvyn thanks! it solved my problem. I shared my working solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(token):
    try:
        return Token.objects.get(key=token).user
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()

class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        # Store the ASGI application we were passed
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):

        return TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance(scope, self)

class TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance:
    """
    Inner class that is instantiated once per scope.
    """

    def __init__(self, scope, middleware):
        self.middleware = middleware
        self.scope = dict(scope)
        self.inner = self.middleware.inner

    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        headers = dict(self.scope['headers'])

        token_name, token_key = headers[b'sec-websocket-protocol'].decode().split(', ')
        
        if token_name == 'Token':
            self.scope['user'] = await get_user(token_key)

        else:
            self.scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        # Instantiate our inner application
        inner = self.inner(self.scope)

        return await inner(receive, send)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked really well on Django 3.2.3 too. =D

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your function in `database_sync_to_async`, it will handle the connections for you

```
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope):
        # Close old database connections to prevent usage of timed out connections
        sync_to_async(close_old_connections)()

        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        try:
            token_name, token_key = headers[b'sec-websocket-protocol'].decode().split(', ')
            
            if token_name == 'Token':
                user = await self.get_user(token)
                scope['user'] = user
            
            else:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
   
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self, token):
        token = Token.ojbects.get(key=token)
        return token.user
```

Comment: I get this error `[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: 'coroutine' object is not callable`

Comment: @Anatol please kindly remove your downvote, thanks, I didnt vote you down

Comment: thanks for letting me know. it says you need to edit your answer before I can change my vote again

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I was having the same issue along with others. I updated django channels and then changed my routing from

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

to

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

You need django channels 3.0+ to do this (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases/3.0.0.html). Then you can follow https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html#django-authentication to setup your custom middleware.

Reference:
[Django Channel Custom Authentication Middleware __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'receive' and 'send'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625473/django-channel-custom-authentication-middleware-call-missing-2-required-po)